# How to Order by random on a SQL query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sql

How do I change the last line to order by rand? Now it's sorting by date of my woocommerce products.

```
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1 ON (posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
    WHERE
        posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND  (mt1.meta_key = '_sale_price_dates_to' AND mt1.meta_value >= ".time().")

        GROUP BY posts.ID
        **ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC";**
```

Comment: How are you making use of this SQL query? That's a very expensive query, but it can be done with `WP_Query`. Also note that ordering things randomly in an SQL query is hideously expensive. It has to create a brand new table in memory with the same rows but randomly ordered before it can even begin searching

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ORDER BY rand()`, but it's a very heavy query as a temporary table is created for it.

A [`WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) or a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) could be a good alternative to `WPDB` custom query. Both support `'orderby' => 'rand',`…